# Python pandas interpolating series

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I have data in a csv file which appears as:

```
  DateTime       Temp
10/1/2016 0:00  20.35491156
10/1/2016 1:00  19.75320845
10/1/2016 4:00  17.62411292
10/1/2016 5:00  18.30190001
10/1/2016 6:00  19.37101638
```

I am reading this file from csv file as:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
d2 = pd.Series.from_csv(r'C:\PowerCurve.csv')
d3 = d2.interpolate(method='time')
```

My goal is to fill the missing hours 2 and 3 with interpolation based on nearby values. i.e. every time there is are missing data it should do the interpolation.

However, d3 doesn't show any interpolation.

Edit:
Based on suggestions below my Python 2.7 still errors out. I am trying the following:

```
import pandas as pd
d2 = pd.Series.from_csv(r'C:\PowerCurve.csv')
d2.set_index('DateTime').resample('H').interpolate()
```

Error is:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2672, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'set_index'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `interpolate` method after `resample` on an hourly basis.

```
d2.set_index('DateTime').resample('H').interpolate()
```

If `d2` is a series then we don't need the set_index

```
d2.resample('H').interpolate()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide complete solution as I get errors implementing your code?

Comment: @Zanam apologies, df should have been d2. This is now complete code.

Comment: I am using Python2.7 and it errors out. Please see the edit to question above.

Answer (score 3):

Use resample with datetime as index and use one of the methods of [resampling](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#resampling) that fits your need. For instance:

```
df.set_index('DateTime').resample('1H').pad()
Out[23]: 
                          Temp
DateTime                      
2016-10-01 00:00:00  20.354912
2016-10-01 01:00:00  19.753208
2016-10-01 02:00:00  19.753208
2016-10-01 03:00:00  19.753208
2016-10-01 04:00:00  17.624113
2016-10-01 05:00:00  18.301900
2016-10-01 06:00:00  19.371016
```

Comment: Can you please provide complete solution as I get errors implementing your code?

Comment: If you create a Series,  datetime is already the index so you don't need to call set_index