# how to fill missing datatime row with pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

```
index                         valuve
2017-01-25 01:00:00:00          1
2017-01-25 02:00:00:00          5
2017-01-25 03:00:00:00          7
2017-01-25 07:00:00:00          34
2017-01-25 20:00:00:00          45
2017-01-25 24:00:00:00          45
2017-01-26 1:00:00:00           31
```

This dataframe is a 24h record of each day, but it misses some record. How can i insert the missing row into the right place and fill 'nan' to the corresponding value?

Comment: Take a look at `resample`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python pandas interpolating series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39949897/python-pandas-interpolating-series)

Answer (score 1):

Here is complicated `24H` in datetimes, so necessary `replace` it to `23H` and add one hour. Last use [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) for add missing values for 24H `DatetimeIndex`:

```
mask = df.index.str.contains(' 24:')
idx = df.index.where(~mask, df.index.str.replace(' 24:', ' 23:'))
idx = pd.to_datetime(idx, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')
df.index = idx.where(~mask, idx + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='H'))
df = df.asfreq('H')
print (df)
                     valuve
index                      
2017-01-25 01:00:00     1.0
2017-01-25 02:00:00     5.0
2017-01-25 03:00:00     7.0
2017-01-25 04:00:00     NaN
2017-01-25 05:00:00     NaN
2017-01-25 06:00:00     NaN
2017-01-25 07:00:00    34.0
2017-01-25 08:00:00     NaN
2017-01-25 09:00:00     NaN
2017-01-25 10:00:00     NaN
2017-01-25 11:00:00     NaN
2017-01-25 12:00:00     NaN
2017-01-25 13:00:00     NaN
2017-01-25 14:00:00     NaN
2017-01-25 15:00:00     NaN
2017-01-25 16:00:00     NaN
2017-01-25 17:00:00     NaN
2017-01-25 18:00:00     NaN
2017-01-25 19:00:00     NaN
2017-01-25 20:00:00    45.0
2017-01-25 21:00:00     NaN
2017-01-25 22:00:00     NaN
2017-01-25 23:00:00     NaN
2017-01-26 00:00:00    45.0
2017-01-26 01:00:00    31.0
```